# asp.net toggle jquery code from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using jquery.loadmask to mask a web page while it is pulling data like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnSubmit").bind("click", function () {
                $("#lowerContent").mask("Waiting...");
            });
        });
</script>
```

Once the data has been pulled I need to be able to unmask the page using this code:

```
        $("#lowerContent").unmask();
```

How can I call/inject this code from the c# code behind file so I can remove the mask?

Ideally if I can call that from an event response.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("jQuery(function($){ $(\"#lowerContent\").unmask(); }");
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", sb.ToString());
```

Comment: I assume that will not work unless a postback is invoked right? Which there isn't for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to achieve by while working with code behind, you will get that only by using ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript method. Or if you pull data using only  ajax javascript call [NO Code-Behind call]. Because as you call code behind, your page will be postback and javascript written in document.ready() will execute. so you can do it.

Comment: Postback is actually not executing, what is happening in code behind, an excel sheet is created and presented to the user so he can save/open it then it stops. If it were to postback I would be sorted. If it does post back then it skips over the save/open file dialog.